# Fatal error: No compiled in support for x86_64

Tags: linux, gcc, build

I am trying to build 32 bit application on amd64 platform. Here is the error that I'm gettin.

```
    installing in src/lib/alignment...
    make[3]: Entering directory `/slowfs/am04dwt2p015/samhov/proj_samhov/embedit_main32/embedit/src/lib/alignment'
    rm -f alignment.o
    /depot/gcc-4.5.2-static/bin/g++ -m64 -ffloat-store -fPIC -c -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall 
-Woverloaded-virtual  -I../../../include            -I../classlib       -I../config
-I../config_autochar            -I../rtb            -I../vlscl            -I../gdbio
-I../gdsii            -I../gds            -I../planet            -I../toucan
-I../decipher            -I /usr/local/buildpkgs/rev9/vltcl/include         
-I /usr/local/buildpkgs/rev9/boost-1.41/include  -Dlinux -DLINUX -DSynopsys_amd64 
-D__amd64__ -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L         -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE
-D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -DUSE_LICENSE_MANAGER 
-DCOMPILE_TCL    alignment.cc
    Assembler messages:
    Fatal error: No compiled in support for x86_64
    make[3]: *** [alignment.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/slowfs/am04dwt2p015/samhov/proj_samhov/embedit_main32/embedit/src/lib/alignment'
```

I am using 64 bit gcc-4.5.2.

Also want to mention that on the same platform 64 bit application is building and working fine.

Comment: Same platform, but different compiler, or in this case, assembler.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `gcc -m32` (i.e. `gcc-multilib` package on Debian etc...) and you should have installed the 32 bits variant of the needed libraries (i.e. `ia32-libs-dev` package on Debian).